# Javascript SetInterval Use Else Only Once

Tags: javascript

I need else {} to work only once. How I can do this? Thank you.

```
    setInterval(function(){
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT `dog` FROM `pets` WHERE `name`=`nice`', function(err, row, fields) {
   var nice_pet = (row[0].dog);
                                                                mysqlConnection.query('SELECT `food` FROM `info`', function(err, row, fields) {
        mysqlConnection.query('SELECT COUNT(Distinct food) AS DistinctCount FROM `something', function(err, row, fields) {
            var check = row[0].DistinctCount;
            if (check <= 10) {
        // Do it many times
         } else {
        // Do it only once if it goes to here
         }
    })
    })
    })
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Can you beautify this code a little ? Like adding a nice indentation (4 spaces), nice line breaks etc ...
It will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a flag, and use it as a condition in an `else if`

```
var once = false;
setInterval(function(){
  mysqlConnection.query('SELECT `dog` FROM `pets` WHERE `name`=`nice`', function(err, row, fields) {
    var nice_pet = (row[0].dog);
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT `food` FROM `info`', function(err, row, fields) {
      mysqlConnection.query('SELECT COUNT(Distinct food) AS DistinctCount FROM `something', function(err, row, fields) {
        var check = row[0].DistinctCount;
        if (check <= 10) {
          // Do it many times
        } else if(!once) {
          once = true;
          // Do it only once if it goes to here
        }
      })
    })
  })
}, 1000);
```